# Loop and join string

Tags: python, pandas

I have an bill of material (BOM) in the following format (.csv):

| part | component | variant | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | C1 |  | 1 |
| P1 | C2 | A | 5 |
| P1 | C3 | B | 2 |
| P1 | C4 |  | 3 |
| P2 | C4 | A | 3 |
| P2 | C5 | C | 5 |
| P2 | C6 |  | 9 |
| P3 | C1 |  | 1 |
| P3 | C7 |  | 3 |

Each part consists of one or more components with the corresponding quantity. If a variant is chosen all components without variant and with the chosen variant are used.

The result should be the following:

| part | component | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1-A | C1 | 1 |
| P1-A | C2 | 5 |
| P1-A | C4 | 4 |
| P1-B | C1 | 1 |
| P1-B | C3 | 2 |
| P1-B | C4 | 4 |
| P2-A | C4 | 3 |
| P2-A | C6 | 9 |
| P2-C | C5 | 5 |
| P2-C | C6 | 9 |
| P3 | C1 | 1 |
| P3 | C7 | 3 |

I want to realize this with Python.

My approach would be the following: Define a string for each part number which consists of every possible variant (e.g. 'AB' for part P1). Join the variant string for each row per part number. Use pandas explode.

I tried to following:

```
for i in df['part'].unique():
    df_2 = df[df.part == i]
    variants = "".join(df_2['variant'].dropna().unique().tolist())
```

This iterates through every part number and overrides 'variants' with the variant string of the part number 'i'.

How do I join the variant string to each part row while looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us load the data -- I assume the empty cells for 'variant' are in fact NaNs

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO('''
part    component   variant quantity
P1  C1      1
P1  C2  A   5
P1  C3  B   2
P1  C4      3
P2  C4  A   3
P2  C5  C   5
P2  C6      9
P3  C1      1
P3  C7      3
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep = '\t')
df
```

df looks like this

```
    part    component    variant      quantity
--  ------  -----------  ---------  ----------
 0  P1      C1           nan                 1
 1  P1      C2           A                   5
 2  P1      C3           B                   2
 3  P1      C4           nan                 3
 4  P2      C4           A                   3
 5  P2      C5           C                   5
 6  P2      C6           nan                 9
 7  P3      C1           nan                 1
 8  P3      C7           nan                 3
```

Next we figure out all possible variants for each part:

```
variants = df.fillna('').groupby(['part'])['variant'].agg(''.join)
```

looks like this:

```
part
P1    AB
P2    AC
P3      
Name: variant, dtype: object
```

Next we fill NaNs for each part with the corresponding value from `variants` and convert it into a list

```
df['variant'] = \
     (df.set_index('part')['variant']
        .fillna(variants)
        .reset_index(drop = True)
        .apply(list)
    )
```

df now looks like this:

```
    part    component    variant       quantity
--  ------  -----------  ----------  ----------
 0  P1      C1           ['A', 'B']           1
 1  P1      C2           ['A']                5
 2  P1      C3           ['B']                2
 3  P1      C4           ['A', 'B']           3
 4  P2      C4           ['A']                3
 5  P2      C5           ['C']                5
 6  P2      C6           ['A', 'C']           9
 7  P3      C1           []                   1
 8  P3      C7           []                   3
```

Next we `explode` these lists and combine `part` and variant`

```
df2 = df.explode('variant').fillna('')
df2['part'] = df2['part'] + '-' + df2['variant']
df2.sort_values('part').drop(columns = ['variant'])
```

and we get, finally

```
    part    component      quantity
--  ------  -----------  ----------
 0  P1-A    C1                    1
 1  P1-A    C2                    5
 3  P1-A    C4                    3
 0  P1-B    C1                    1
 2  P1-B    C3                    2
 3  P1-B    C4                    3
 4  P2-A    C4                    3
 6  P2-A    C6                    9
 5  P2-C    C5                    5
 6  P2-C    C6                    9
 7  P3-     C1                    1
 8  P3-     C7                    3
```

`P3` gets a somewhat unfortunate trailing `-`, hope it is ok